# Cypress select last option in dropdown

Tags: select, cypress, dynamic-content

I have a dynamically generated dropdown with normal structure as:

```js
<select>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
etc.
</select>
```

It is kind of pagination and I don't know how many items will be in the table and don't want to calculate how many options with which numbers will be in dropdown according to item count.

What I want to achieve with Cypress is simply always select the last option.

I know I can select any option by name or value, e.g. `cy.get('select').select('10')`

Also with index: `cy.get('select').select(0)`

But I don't know the last index.

I also tried `select().last()` but this doesn't work, as `select` must not be empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your options are dynamic, you should ensure the list is populated before selecting

```js
cy.get('select option')
  .should('have.length.gt', 0)

cy.get('select option')
  .last()
  .then($lastOption => {
    cy.get('select').select($lastOption.text())
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this. First get the number of options and then using that select the last item.

```js
cy.get('select')
  .find('option')
  .its('length')
  .then((len) => {
    cy.get('select').select(len - 1)
  })
```

Comment: I'm sure you can replace the `.its()` and `.then()` with `.last()` since the `.find('option')` will return an array of al the options inside of the `select`.

Comment: I have to try it, and I notice that cypress still wants you to use the .select() when dealing with select tags and options

Comment: You can get the last option and its value but you cannot select it. `click()` will not work and cypress pushes you to use the select() method.